# Architecture and patterns for cash collection terminals

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, hardware, windows-xp-embedded

I have just been handed a huge project for an application that must run on a terminal that securely collects cash drops.  It is a rewrite of an existing project, so requirements are pretty well defined, [this is the product](http://www.smartec.co.za/Products/P3100.aspx).  Although my employer will supply me most application specific new requirements, I would like some general advice on architectural aspects and areas that I should pay attention to in order to ensure maximum quality for my rewrite.  The application will run on XP Embedded.

Hopefully folk who have written such applications can maybe advise me on areas to focus on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I have no experience with what you are going to implement, and I didn't take this book, but when I read your question I just remembered its title and idea that it can be useful pop up: "[Real-Time Design Patterns: Robust Scalable Architecture for Real-Time Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201699567)" (check also book advice from amazon customers under that book)
Here is [google book](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=drlsKjcw3xQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Real-Time+Design+Patterns%22&source=bl&ots=MKUw-ZBMsB&sig=NwZ5Y1Vm56m8NVqiIHXvyvIEPgU&hl=uk&ei=1n4tTfuNI8rtsgbih8z9Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) link, so you can check its content

Btw, you will have client-server systems, maybe another integration needed, so there is another interesting book in that area which I read: [Enterprise Integration Patterns: Designing, Building, and Deploying Messaging Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321200683) and alternative, similar catalog of SOA patterns http://www.soapatterns.org/ - just in case you will need integration and its security.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a worthwhile read.  I'll see if I can get the boss to buy it.  However, fortunately I don't have the severe requirements of many real time systems w.r.t. timing, concurrency etc.

Comment: yes, book is old, but still worth. If you don't need many parts of it, you can just get some info/input from google books service (in case your boss will be not willing..)